# Indexing on varbinary column vs varchar vs int - which is fast

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-performance

Do we have any performance benefit if creating an index on a binary column instead of string column. Which of the two will be fast. I know varchar will be slow in comparison to numeric values. Since binary values must be getting read directly, I am expecting it should be fast probably fasted.

**EDIT:**

Actual use case is if I have GUID column, I can use CHECKSUM or HASHBYTES to avoid string comparison.

I know we can't create index on `MAX`. It is only about varchar(25), varbinary(25), int. There is no point of varchar(max)

Comment: One thing :an index cannot be created on a column over 900 bytes. Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be specified as key columns for an index

Comment: What data is stored in this column? How big in size will this content be?

Comment: Use the appropriate data type for your data. Don't try to out smart sql server.

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` is stored as a 16 byte binary data. Not as a string.

Comment: will it be fast then?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Do I understand you correctly? You are storing a GUID into a string   column (=VARCHAR) and now you want to know how this is best in performance? Just use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER which **is** GUID. This is pretty fast and good with indexes (But be aware not to use it as CLUSTERED index as this will be fragmented and slow your system down again!)

Comment: No, I am not storing GUID into a varchar column. I am just comparing the two a GUID stored in a column vs same length string column which one is fast and why? Up to what extent we can see better performance with GUID compared to string i.e in terms of data type length

Comment: @ShantanuGupta, I cannot see the point... What do you really want to achieve? The answer in short: GUID (=UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) is a fix binary format -> (relatively) easy to compare -> (relatively) fast. VARCHAR is not stored within the row but is referenced, indexes use some kind of hashing -> slow. To put it in short: GUID and STRING are completely different things. You should not muddle them up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the size of the column, but for two columns of the same size the varbinary will *typically* be faster. The other factor involved here is the collation used for the column. The default collation in Sql Server is not case senstive, meaning for for compare purposes `SOME RANDOM KEY`, `some random key`, and every permutation thereof are all the *same* value, and therefore the database must do extra work when comparing and sorting those keys to know what goes where and what value matches what other values: it's not just a straight byte-for-byte comparison anymore.

Comment: so would that mean, binary operations are fast compared to even numeric at least for same size. i.e. int(4 bytes) vs binary(4 bytes) so binary will be fast here?

Comment: No, the `int` comparison will be faster, because there's cpu support for it: comparing two integers is a single cpu instruction.